# What is the name of this multivariable derivative?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

This is (hopefully) the definition of a tangent vector based on curves (M is a manifold):
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{[\gamma;\phi;\phi^{-1};f](0 + t\cdot1) - [\gamma;\phi;\phi^{-1};f](0)}{t}
$$
where $\gamma\colon \mathbb{R}\to M$, $\phi\colon M\to\mathbb{R}^{k}$, $\phi^{-1}\colon \mathbb{R}^{k}\to M$, $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$ (used ; for diagrammatic composition).

This made me wonder: why only one parameter? Is there any derivative that is like this:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{[\Gamma;\phi;\phi^{-1};F](0 + t\cdot X) - [\gamma;\phi;\phi^{-1};F](0)}{t}
$$
with $\Gamma\colon \mathbb{R}^m\to M$ and $F\colon M\to \mathbb{R}^n$, and what is it called in that case?

(Guess: maybe this variant is used for maps between manifolds? I just remember a lot of talk about "implicit function theorem" when reading about that...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your notation. Is $[f;g;h]=f\circ g\circ h$? If yes, then it seems to be a case of $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x+ta)-f(x)}{t}=af'(x)$.

Comment: [f;g;h](x)=h(g(f(x)))=h○g○f. It is how the input flows to output so to speak and easier to read than the commonly used composition imo :) I want to know what this multidimensional surface variant of the tangent vector means.

Comment: Okay. Then the $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ cancel each other and what you have is $F(\gamma(t))$ which is a function from the reals to the reals. Observe that $[\gamma;\phi;\phi^{-1};F]=[\gamma;F]=F\circ\gamma$. The first thing is the derivative of a function along a curve. The second one is a scaled version, and can be identified with $XdF(\dot\gamma(t))=X\frac{d}{dt}F(\gamma(t))$. (You don't need to define $dF$ or $\dot\gamma$ to make sense of the derivative, though.) It's the derivative scaled by the real number $X$. It all seems to come to this: $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x+ta)-f(x)}{t}=af'(x)$.

Comment: Well, the definition on wikipedia said the equation was chart-independent but I included the charts anyway. What stumps me is that the definition on wikipedia was from reals to reals. So they obviously cheat somewhere and take a cartesian product without writing it out? Right? Otherwise the only functions in differential geometry that is allowed to derivate are real valued functions?

Comment: I am trying to create a working definition for the riemann tensor and am working my way up. I have looked at the equations defining derivatives in terms of derivatives. It is obviously recursive so an actual limit is needed to compute it in the end.

Comment: There's no cheat. The functions $F$ and $\gamma$ both individually needs charts to describe or differentiate, but the composed function $F\circ\gamma$ does not. It really honestly is a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ without any weird identifications or anything.

Comment: Okay, but then what you said can't be the full story. if X(f) is real it cannot be $\mathbb{R}^n$ when n is not one.

Comment: I think you missed that I mean $\gamma: \mathbb{R}^m\to M$.

Comment: I missed that indeed. Then the composed function is $\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$. The notation $\gamma$ is often reserved for curves, and that made me miss the exponent. I can elaborate tomorrow if no one else does.

Comment: @Joonas Will edit to use different variables in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will clarify things a little.

In more typical notation $[\Gamma;\phi;\phi^{-1};F]=F\circ\phi^{-1}\circ\phi\circ\Gamma$.
Since $\phi^{-1}\circ\phi\colon M\to M$ is the identity, we have in fact $F\circ\phi^{-1}\circ\phi\circ\Gamma=F\circ\Gamma=:G$.
This $G$ is a map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, so you can define its derivative in the usual Euclidean way.

It should be a familiar result from multivariable calculus that
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{G(x+tX)-G(x)}{t}
=
DG(x) X
$$
for any $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $X\in\mathbb R^n$.
Here $DG$ is the derivative matrix of $G$.
This is the directional derivative in the direction of $X$ at the point $x$.

Notice that both $F$ and $\Gamma$ require coordinates on the manifold to describe and differentiate, but the composition does not<sup>1</sup>.
The composed function is an honest function from a Euclidean space to another one.
If you differentiate using the chain rule, then coordinates come into play, although it can be more convenient to write things in an invariant form.

Your first derivative can be written as $df(\dot\gamma)$.
Here the differential $df$ is in the cotangent space $T_{\gamma(0)}^*M$ and $\dot\gamma(0)\in T_{\gamma(0)}M$.
This makes $df(\dot\gamma)$ naturally a scalar.

In the second case $dF_{\Gamma(0)}$ is a linear map $T_{\Gamma(0)}M\to T_{F(\Gamma(0))}\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^n$.
The chain rule says $DG(x)=dF_{\Gamma(x)}\circ d\Gamma_x$.
Now $x=0$, so the derivative you want to calculate is
$$
DG(0)X
=
dF_{\Gamma(0)}\circ d\Gamma_0 X.
$$
Now $d\Gamma_0 X$ is a tangent vector at $\Gamma(0)$.

You can often study a function $G$ from anywhere to $\mathbb R^n$ component by component.
It makes no real difference that the target is multidimensional.
Also, assuming everything is nice and smooth, the derivative only depends on $\Gamma$ restricted to the one-dimensional subspace $X\mathbb R\subset\mathbb R^n$.
So from a certain point of view having $n>1$ has little effect on the differential geometry here.

---

<sup>1</sup>
If a function is defined to or from a manifold, you can always use the invariant objects to differentiate them. But often it is best to use some local coordinates on the manifold. When you do so, you get a coordinate representation of the derivative. The differentials $dF$ and $dΓ$ will depend on the choice of coordinates, but the differential of $G$ will not.

Comment: Ok just one question, the "describe and differentiate" with $F$ and $\Gamma$ on their own, how does that work? We need to compose it into something that goes from euclidian spaces to euclidian spaces to compute the differential? I don't know if you answered my question but I'll tag it for your effort.

Comment: Your question wasn't given precisely, so it's hard for anyone to tell whether I answered it. :) Maybe based on this explanation you can ask a more precise question. // If a function is defined to or from a manifold, you can always use the invariant objects to differentiate them. But often it is best to use some local coordinates on the manifold. When you do so, you get a coordinate representation of the derivative. The differentials $dF$ and $d\Gamma$ will depend on the choice of coordinates, but the differential of $G$ will not. That was what I tried to say. I edited the answer.

Comment: Okay. I remember in complex analysis that it used curves in the derivative proof and complex numbers are like RxR with special multiplication so maybe that is one implication of the 1D-subspace-if-it-is-smooth-thing you wrote. I probably wanted to ask about functional derivatives that took n-dimensional surfaces in as the "direction" of the derivative. Or maybe I wanted to hear if it was something like morphing the shape of the manifold depending on which way one took the derivative. It is hard to write a question when you only have a hunch about what you want to ask. Thanks for the answer!